# Unable to submit Android apk for my existing app over 100 mb

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I was uploading apk of around 150mb from last 2 years but today when i am trying to upload same size build it is giving error
"You need to reduce your APK file size to 100MB or use APK expansion files."

was there any timeline that i missed.
I did upload last build on 20 April 2022 and size was 157 mb.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files